# Раздельный доступ к изображению каждого глаза Oculus в Unreal Engine 4.24.3

Tags: unreal-engine-4, oculus

Подскажите пожалуйста как в Unreal Engine 4.24.3 получить доступ к камерам Oculus, чтобы в BluePrints проводить манипуляции с каждой камерой по отдельности? Или второй вариант - как взять две отдельные камеры и отображать изображение для каждого глаза?

**Update 1:**  Пишут, что можно создать 'Stereo Layer' для каждого глаза и указать какой глаз должен быть к нему привязан. Пока не удалось справиться.

**Update 2:** Ещё нашел комментарий на форуме - "Сделал это, используя “ScreenPosition” node в материале. Если координата x < 0.5 показываем одну текстуру, иначе другую". Не совсем понятно как это осуществить. В BluePrint UE4.24.3 и UE4.27.2 не нашел команду 'Screen Position'.